# Need a C programming logic code for a simple puzzle

Tags: c, puzzle

A shop sells one chocolate @ Rs.1 each, and In exchange of 3 wrappers gives one chocolate again? I want to know the C program logic for this? Have tried it, but getting wrong result.

Output should look like:

Enter the amount given to shopkeeper in Rs. 50

```
-> Total number of chocolates: 74
-> Wrappers remaining: 2
```

Comment: post code otherwise should we mindread?

Comment: Please elaborate on the example, I have no idea how you came up with these numbers, the problem is unclear. Is it just summation?

Comment: Please don't ask for solutions to your homework. Post your code and ask for help if you face issues with the code.

Comment: I have my code in place, its not giving me the correct output, hence did not write it here. @Peter thanks for correcting.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page soon -- having been a member for 11 months, indications are you haven't done that yet. For now, read [How do I ask a good question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

your example is wrong:

```
50@ = 50 chocolate wrapper
-> 16 choc (and 2 wrapper left)
-> 5 choc (+1 wrapper left)
-> 1 chock (+2 wrapper left)
-> 5 wrapper -> 1 chock + 2left
-> 3 wrapper -> 1 chock
```

it should be 74

```
50@ -> 50c + 0w -> 0c + 50w -> 16c + 2w -> 0c + 18w -> 6c + 0w -> 0c + 6w -> 2c + 0w -> 0c + 2w.
```

pseudocode:

```
chock = money;
geschock = 0;
wrapper = 0;

while chock > 3 {
  geschock += chock;
  wrapper = modulo((chock+wrapper), 3);
  chock = (chock+wrapper) / 3;
}
```

Comment: int main()
{
 int price=0, tot_choc=0, wrappers=0, choc_wrap=0;
 printf("Enter price in Rs.");
 scanf("%d",&price);
 tot_choc = price;
 wrappers = price;
 
 while (wrappers>=3)
 {
  choc_wrap=wrappers/3;
  tot_choc+=choc_wrap;
  wrappers=choc_wrap + (wrappers%3);
 }
 printf("\nWrappers left: %d",wrappers);
 printf("\nTotal no. of choclates: %d",tot_choc);
 getch();
 return 1;
}